# Creating an Array class from a UML diagram with a working driver class in java

Tags: java, arrays, uml

I am having the most difficult time trying to convert a UML diagram into runnable java code. I am given:

> Array
>
> - array:double[]
>
> +setArray(arr:double[]):void
>   +isInIncreasingOrder():boolean
>   +isInDecreasingOrder():boolean
>   +getTotal():double
>   +getAverage():double

I am not given what the length of the array should be, so I am assuming that the user must input them. It then asks for a driver class TestArray to test all of the methods. 
So far, this is all I have, and I can't seem to find how else to go about finishing it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array
{
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

private double[] array = new double[];

public void setArray(double[] arr)
{
//I must set a value for the array length. set by user.
//user must input data
}

public boolean isInIncreasingOrder()
{
//must test if input is in increasing order
}

public boolean isInDecreasingOrder()
{
//must test if input is in descending order
}

public double getTotal()
{
//must find the total of all input
//total +=total
}

public double getAverage()
{
//must calculate average
//average = total/array.length
}
}
```

I know basically how to get user input, but without a proper Driver Class I can't run anything and make sure it works?

Comment: Make your own `TestArray` class, run it on the `Array` class without accepting user input.  That's typically how automated tests are done, and probably what's wanted here.

Comment: I don't understand why you think you need user input, or why you think you don't know the length of the argument to `setArray()`.  Java arrays are full-blown objects, and they know their own lengths.  You can access an array's length via the form `arr.length`; it is of type `int`.

Comment: I am afraid I still do not understand. What would I even put in the driver class?

Comment: You might want to look up how JUnit Testcases work.